# GMail breakpoints to hide/expand an email

Tags: email, gmail, javascript

**Description of the issue**

I am sending emails in JavaScript with

```
message2 = message.replace("<br>", "\n")       
GmailApp.sendEmail(address, subject, message2, {
      cc: cc,
      name: sendername,
      htmlBody: message
    });
```

…where `message` is a long string containing HTML tags.

On my Gmail account the email that is received contains a `…` in the middle to hide/extend the end of the message. The `…` correspond to newlines (`<br>`) but it seems to chose a newline randomly that will be used to split the message randomly.

I cannot get rid of all `<br>` of course. I always saw these `…` to separate the main part of the email from the signature. But in my case it just appears anywhere as for example right after the first line:

[image]

**Question**

- How does GMail choses the “breakpoints” for shortening the message?
- How can I avoid that GMail uses “breakpoints?”
- Should I use something else than `<br>` to make newlines?